# Importing online data into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, import

I have been tasked with streamlining a process to collect data from a specific online website and import it into an Excel 2010 spreadsheet. Website is 'Web of Science', http://apps.webofknowledge.com/UA_GeneralSearch_input.do?product=UA&SID=T2b1MtfKgCqeB2h9j9J&search_mode=GeneralSearch which is a site that details academic publications and journals.

Currently they are going to the website, entering a short number of search parameters and then manually recording the pertinent data from the webpage. They would like to be able to enter a keyword in Excel (which acts as the search item) which then automatically does the rest of the process and provides them with a spreadsheet of the required data.

The data they require however comes in the form of a list of potential authors for the entered publication name which currently comes up on the website as a selection of check-boxes under 'Refine Results': http://apps.webofknowledge.com/RAMore.do?product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&SID=T2b1MtfKgCqeB2h9j9J&qid=5&ra_mode=more&ra_name=Author&colName=&viewType=raMore

So basically I need the user to be able to enter the search item in Excel that they would enter into the search field on the website, and then import a list of authors relevant to that subject into a spreadsheet.

Is this possible? Perhaps by using VBA code within Excel?

What would people recommend? I am really only a novice Excel user but do have programming experience.

Thank you very much for your help,

John

*FYI, update, this is what I have so far which gets as far as a user entering a word which is then searched for by the website search facility.  Now need to get the authors and import them into the spreadsheet:

```
Sub WoS()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True

navigate:

    ' navigate to the relevant website
    IE.navigate "http://apps.webofknowledge.com/UA_GeneralSearch_input.do?   product=UA&search_mode=GeneralSearch&SID=T23ZytENYQRHyJkmixB&preferencesSaved="

    ' wait until page has finished loading
    Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set Doc = IE.document

    If Doc Is Nothing Then GoTo navigate

    ' allow user to input keywords for search
    Set myInput = Doc.getelementbyid("value(input1)")
    myInput.Value = InputBox("Please enter the subject for Publication Name: ")

    ' click button to process search
    Set btnSubmit = Doc.getelementbyid("UA_GeneralSearch_input_form_sb")
    btnSubmit.Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use Power Query? With Power QUery you can download the data straight from the Web (and also transform and clean them) and then use in workbook. All data are saved as "proces" so you can simple refresh the content from the web. Another option is of course the code ie VBA. When i will be able to check your adresses i will let you know if it is possible to get the data from this sites.